# Стоит ли кавычить?

Tags: кавычки

Ув. филологи! Стоит ли кавычить выражение "тучные годы"?

...кризис ли на дворе или "тучные годы"...

Также интересует, нужна ли запятая перед "или".

Answer (score 2):

Кавычки лучше поставить, так как это выражение считается метафорой (слова "тучный" с таким значением, даже переносным, в словаре нет).

Запятая не нужна, так как  ИЛИ - одиночный разделительный союз, связывающий однородные члены.

Answer (score 1):

Союз *ли...или* связывает однородные члены, поэтому запятая не нужна. В сложносочиненном предложении (в отличие от простого с однородными членами)  *ли...или* рассматривается как повторяющийся союз и запятая ставится. Сравните:

*Видит ли он это или не видит?* (между однородными членами)

О*на хотела знать, принял ли он ее предложение, или оно ему не понравилось* (между однородными частями сложного предложения - придаточными).

*Уймись, или плохо будет* (между простыми предложениями в составе сложного).

*Было ли это случайностью, или кто-то это спланировал?* (между вопросительными предложениями)

А что касается кавычек, думаю, можно закавычить только слово "тучные", ведь только это слово употребляется в необычном значении.